# What are the Web Frameworks worth investing some time and effort into these days

Tags: ruby-on-rails, development-environment

I saw an interesting video replay of a presentation by Avi Bryant who claims the rails (MVC) framework (along with most others) is obsolete. Here is the link here: [Rails Is Obsolete (But so is everything else).](http://speakerrate.com/talks/4501-rails-is-obsolete-but-so-s-everything-else)

Summary of the presentation follows.  So if you were going invest time in a new framework/platform today what would it be and why?  I'll throw out a couple of candidates for discussion purposes I'm sure I'm missing a lot of great candidates.

- Cappuccio
- Spoutcore
- Coccoa / IOS
- Google / GWT
- Seaside
- Rails 3 (Because Rails is not obsolete)

Back in the old days, you submitted a form to some URL and you got back some HTML. These days, you probably didn't hit submit, your URL probably didn't change, and what you got back was probably JSON—but you never saw it because it came in asynchronously in the background. Best practices around web applications are changing fast, driven by new browser standards, sophisticated JavaScript libraries and super fast JavaScript implementations. Why would a web framework design from 2004 still be appropriate? What can we be doing to adapt, or reinvent, our approaches to building web apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, given your example list, I assume you're not limiting it to a Ruby discussion?

here's a few worth considering:

- Sinatra
- NancyFX (on the .NET side)
- ServiceStack (on the .NET side)
- Android (since you have iOS)

Comment: Thanks for the input. I've never heard of NancyFX or ServiceStack. I'll check those out today.